# Lost hard drive space to Boot Camp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, macos, filevault, core-storage

Boot Camp caused ~200 GB of my 750 GB HD to disappear and I cannot re(un)-partition it through Disk Utility and when I try to reformat the storage through the terminal using:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume
```

with the appropriate name and size this is what it tells me

```
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 4D5406D2-B7BC-4719-AC41-DC984D4CCB53
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair
```

What else can I try and/or what should I do?  I couldn't find any answered questions that helped but please link any that you think are helpful.

EDIT (Adding what klanomath suggested in the order suggested)
My OS X is 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

```
Ethans-MacBook-Pro:~ Runnur$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            749.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +478.9 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 4D5406D2-B7BC-4719-AC41-DC984D4CCB53
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

Ethans-MacBook-Pro:~ Runnur$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 47A55214-3C57-401E-8F66-56D4E6F13A08
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         749296615424 B (749.3 GB)
    Free Space:   270018936832 B (270.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume F483D699-F77C-40C1-823F-8E57C82FEDC1
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     749296615424 B (749.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 66FF454B-18C8-417E-AF73-118390F52AD1
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 4D5406D2-B7BC-4719-AC41-DC984D4CCB53
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          478925357056 B (478.9 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            Revert Status:         Reboot required
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS

Ethans-MacBook-Pro:~ Runnur$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1463469952      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1463879592     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1465149128           7         
  1465149135          32         Sec GPT table
  1465149167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: If you provide much more information (`diskutil list`, `diskutil cs list`, `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and the OS X version)  you will get an answer soon. Please add this to your answer by editing it.

Comment: Did you do as the error message suggested, "you should run whole-disk repair"?

Comment: Thanks @klanomath for the suggestion, I added all of it.  user3439894 when I run first aid on the disk (in safe mode and not in safe mode) it says that it will repair it if needed and it recognizes that the size is incorrect but does nothing,  if there is another step in disk utility other than selecting the disk and then running first aid on it please let me know, I don't know to much about this stuff and everything I found online either didn't apply due to different situations or the action(s) described was not available.

Answer (score 1):

If Disk Utility (booted to Internet Recovery Mode) can't repair the error, there is nothing else than booting to your main volume, backing up everything to an external disk and after rebooting to Recovery Mode deleting the Logical Volume and re-adding a new one.

If that fails you have to delete the Logical Volume Group as well. Create a new one - including a new Logical Volume.

Restore your backup and boot to your main volume again.

Finally enable FileVault and encrypt your main volume.